# Is there a word or expression meaning "intelligent AND wise"?

Tags: synonyms

In my book there are dumb wise people, and brilliant unwise people, and so on.

Two distinct dimensions.

Is there a term for "intelligent and wise"?

Comment: Intelligent is a complicated word because it has so many different meanings based on context. Do you mean having strong reasoning skills or having a wide and/or deep knowledge base, or being apt at learning new things?

Comment: Definitely not knowledge base. I would call that "knowledgeable". I mean intelligent in the "classic" sense along the lines of cognitive prowess, IQ, etc.

Comment: @Nosajimiki "Having a wide and/or deep knowledge base": that is "knowledgeable", not intelligent.

Comment: If you’re ***savvy***  you probably exhibit some of both.

Comment: Explain what your dimensions are in as much detail as possible. Do you mean: knowing lots of things; able to apply knowledge to real-world situations; skilled at abstract/numerical reasoning; skilled at lateral thinking; skilled at science, language, economics, math, or some other discipline; able to relate to people and understand them; artistic and creative; witty; able to solve practical problems; having good powers of deduction like Sherlock Holmes; having a lot of life experience they can draw upon; knowing lots of people; knowing where to get information; or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe calling someone "a sage" fits the bill.
Merriam Webster defines sage as

> 1: one (such as a profound philosopher) distinguished for wisdom
> 2: a mature or venerable person of sound judgment

Comment: It seems to stay in the vicinity of "wise". There's really no notion of high IQ anywhere near "sound judgement" or "wisdom".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **perspicacious**. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perspicacious) has

> **perspicacious**
> quick in noticing, understanding, or judging things accurately

Answer (score 0):

The second case is easier to see than the first, perhaps a boffin who knows the exact volume of a jar but not how to open it.

The first seems more tricky: perhaps a worldly-wise person who is illiterate.

Could your balanced person be an

- **educated all-rounder**?

where 'educated' does not necessarily mean *formally* educated.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all-rounder) has

> **all-rounder**
> a person who has many different types of skills and abilities

Comment: "all-rounder" is a vague and general concept. It is not about intelligence + wisdom in particular. In fact you can be an all-rounder while being neither intelligent nor wise.

Comment: My answer was not an "all-rounder", who might have abilities purely by talent.

Answer (score 0):

### The word you are looking for could be Intelligence or Wisdom, but the words you are starting with are misinformed.

When people compare "Intelligence" and "Wisdom", they typically mean very narrow definitions of these words that they probably learned from playing Dungeons and Dragons or similar games derived from it.  In systems like D&D, Intelligence is your ability to memorize information, and wisdom is a measure of your common sense... the problem here is that D&D has picked two words that each mean both of these things.

> Intelligence has been defined in many ways: the capacity for abstraction, logic, understanding, self-awareness, learning, emotional knowledge, reasoning, planning, creativity, critical thinking, and problem-solving. More generally, it can be described as the ability to perceive or infer information, and to retain it as knowledge to be applied towards adaptive behaviors within an environment or context.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence

Wisdom is similarly vague and inclusive:

> 1a: ability to discern inner qualities and relationships : INSIGHT
>
> b: good sense : JUDGMENT
>
> c: generally accepted belief
>
> d: accumulated philosophical or scientific learning : KNOWLEDGE
>
> 2: a wise attitude, belief, or course of action
>
> 3: the teachings of the ancient wise men
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wisdom

So, instead of trying to figure out what class is above these two almost identical words, you probably need two better words for describing what you think intelligence and wisdom mean.

A better adjective than intelligent for someone who is good at memorizing information but not necessarily good at making well informed choices would be **Eidetic**.  People with certain savant disorders often have eidetic memories, but poor reasoning skills.

> marked by or involving extraordinarily accurate and vivid recall especially of visual images
>
> ~ https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eidetic

A better adjective than wise for someone with good common-since, but not necessarily good memorization skills would be **Intuitive**.  People with certain learning disorders can be very Intuitive, but have poor recall skills.

> 1a: the power or faculty of attaining to direct knowledge or cognition without evident rational thought and inference
>
> b: immediate apprehension or cognition
>
> c: knowledge or conviction gained by intuition
>
> 2: quick and ready insight
>
> ~ https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intuition

Answer (score -1):

The closest equivalent I can think of is "*analytical*". The analytical mind is necessarily that of someone sufficiently intelligent, but in addition experts conceive it as having certain qualities that one is inclined to associate with wisdom: a preference for proven data, readily skeptical, open to new ideas,  … This can be gathered from an attempt at the definition of the analytical mind in this [Quora study](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-analytical-mind).

> The analytical mind, on the other hand, would probably be characterized this way:
>
> - Skilled in coming to conclusions based on a logical thought progression - recognizes when conclusions are from biases or fallacies
> - Prefers to use qualified data and information as input rather than anecdote, emotion, or the opinions of bystanders
> - Can move from abstract to concrete and back again with ease
> - A healthy skepticism about everything, including those things that “everyone knows” - checks things out for herself
> - Openness to new information - all conclusions are tentative and may change
> - Awareness of probability - there is no destiny, only probabilities. Comfortable with “maybe” as an answer
> - Awareness of nuance - few things in life are actually binary; most are somewhere in between, and choices are made on cost/benefit consideration, not on whether they are evil or good